# Обрезать получаемый реультат в PostrgeSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно вытащить данные с `БД` так чтобы они были уникальными и обрезать их.
Обрезать нужно все после останнего символа в строке - `'_'` (обрезать включая символ `'_'`).
То есть если у нас в поле `name` имеются значения - 'Tom_1', 'Tom_2', 'Tom_Rob_3' должно вывести - "Tom", "Tom_Rob"

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
FROM user
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(name_trimmed)
LEFT(name, length(name) - position('_' in reverse(name))) AS name_trimmed
FROM "user"
```

[**Пример в SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9b1c1/3)